# Sql delete from A if exist in B

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

- `USER`
- `MAILING`

`MAILING` table has one column `email`.

`USER` table has many `users` with `email`.

Now I want to delete something like this:

```
DELETE email FROM mailing WHERE users.email = mailings.email
```

So i need to delete email from table mailing if this email exist in user table.

Comment: do you want to delete the rows or set email=null?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL DELETE with JOIN another table for WHERE condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980738/sql-delete-with-join-another-table-for-where-condition)

Comment: I want to delete it. Mailing table should not have emails exist users

Comment: You can simply use **`EXISTS`** clause. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
DELETE FROM mailing WHERE email IN (SELECT email FROM users)
```

or this using `JOIN`

```
DELETE M
FROM mailing M
  JOIN users U
    ON M.email = U.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `update` not `delete` if you want to update a column

```
UPDATE mailing 
inner join users on users.email = mailings.email  
set email=null
```

or you want to delete the records 
TRy this:

```
DELETE m 
FROM mailing m 
inner join users u on u.email=m.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to delete all rows from mailing table, and you've only one column in mailing table.

```
Delete
from mailing where mailing.email 
exists (select email from users where users.email = mailing.email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`EXISTS`** clause of MySQL as follows-

```
delete from mailing where exists(select * from user where user.email=mailing.email);
```

## No Need of using JOIN