# SQL DELETE with JOIN another table on multiple conditions for WHERE NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, mysql-error-1064

I have to delete rows from slaveTable that have no more relation with masterTable table (dead relations, removed from masterTable).

I came up with the statement:

```
DELETE
FROM   slaveTable AS s
LEFT JOIN 
       masterTable AS m 
ON   ( s.key1 = m.key1
AND    s.key2 = m.key2 )
WHERE  m.key1 IS NULL
```

[SQL DELETE with JOIN another table for WHERE condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980738/sql-delete-with-join-another-table-for-where-condition)
shows this way as a solution... but won't work for me. 
Because of my lack of reputation I can't answer there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL DELETE with JOIN another table for WHERE condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980738/sql-delete-with-join-another-table-for-where-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify the table where you want to delete the rows.

```
DELETE s                    -- << HERE: s (alias of slaveTable )
FROM   slaveTable AS s
LEFT JOIN 
       masterTable AS m 
ON   ( s.key1 = m.key1
AND    s.key2 = m.key2 )
WHERE  m.key1 IS NULL
```