# mysql delete with cross table lookup

Tags: mysql, sql

**SQL**

```
DELETE FROM sex s, users u WHERE s.id = 195 and u.id = s.uid and u.sessionCheck = 'd986a074c7549c566bfed1d4ad7ca491'
```

**Error**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's, users u WHERE s.id = 195 and u.id = s.uid and u.sessionCheck = 'd986a074c7549' at line 1
```

So clearly the error is with the joins in the delete. But everything I have tried just won't work.

I am using `Server version: 5.6.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980738/sql-delete-with-join-another-table-for-where-condition

Comment: Disagree @Kermit :) I think its quite a helpful search term, so googling returned me nothing on the problem. If I've had this problem then somebody else will as well.

Comment: @JamieHutber You must be using Google wrong. I searched and it returned 102,000 results.

Comment: @Kermit That's because Google doesn't with documentation...

Comment: @JamieHutber you should restructure that sentence in a way that makes more sense.

Comment: @Zane ... maybe they were going for this ... `WITH Documentation AS (SELECT * FROM [teh].[Googlez]) SELECT * FROM Documentation;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE s /* forgot to mention from which table you like to delete from these 2 */
FROM sex s
join users u on u.id = s.uid 
WHERE s.id = 195
and u.sessionCheck = 'd986a074c7549c566bfed1d4ad7ca491'
```

Comment: So hang on... what is this `DELETE S` this is deleting the entire row, `S` being the reference to `sex`?

Comment: Yes, when joining to have to specify from which tables you delete. It is `delete table_to_delete_from from table_to_delete_from join ...`

Comment: BTW You can specify more than one table and delete from multiple at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE s.* FROM sex s,users u   WHERE u.id = s.uid AND s.id = 195 AND u.sessionCheck = 'd986a074c7549c566bfed1d4ad7ca491'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM sex 
WHERE sex.id IN (SELECT id 
                 FROM users u
                 WHERE u.sessionCheck = 'd986a074c7549c566bfed1d4ad7ca491')
```

To delete from both tables

```
DELETE s.*,u.*
FROM sex s
inner join users u on u.id = s.uid 
WHERE s.id = 195
and u.sessionCheck = 'd986a074c7549c566bfed1d4ad7ca491'
```