# delete records based on join result

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables that are joined by an id. 
Table A is where I define the records.
Table B is where I use the definition and add some data.
I am doing some data normalization and I have realized that on table B there are some ID that are no longer defined in table A.

If I run this query:

```
SELECT B.id_cred, A.id_cre from B LEFT JOIN A ON B.id_cred=A.id_cre
```

I see those records that are NULL on A.id_cre.

I'd like to DELETE from table B those records where the query returns null on table A?

Something like:

```
DELETE FROM B WHERE id IN (SELECT B.id from B LEFT JOIN A ON B.id_cred=A.id_cre WHERE a.id IS NULL)
```

but this query throws an error because table B is target and reference at the same time.

> You can't specify target table B for UPDATE in FROM clause

Note that the join query will return 1408 rows so I need to do it in a massive way

Comment: looks similar to [Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: A SO would have helped you. Please check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980738/sql-delete-with-join-another-table-for-where-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
delete from B
where not exists (select 1 from A where A.id_cre = B.id_cred)
```

Option 2, use a `DELETE` with `JOIN`:

```
delete B
from B
left join A on B.id_cred = A.id_cre
where A.id_cre is null
```

Comment: Thanks. Not exists is what I was looking for. Didn't know this command :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
DELETE FROM B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT id_cre
FROM A
WHERE B.id_cred=A.id_cre)
```

Just delete any row from B where the key does not exist in A.

NOTE: "A" and "B" can't be aliases, they must be the actual table names.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Why not use `id_cre` from A table since both have the id.

This statement:

```
DELETE FROM B WHERE id IN (SELECT B.id from B LEFT JOIN A ON B.id_cred=A.id_cre WHERE a.id IS NULL)
```

simply says that both a and b `(B.id_cred=A.id_cre)` are the same.